# How to remove first Cyrillic letter in string using PHP

Tags: php

How I can remove first Cyrillic letter in string using PHP?

```
$string = 'Добре дошли!';
```

result:

> обре дошли!

Comment: If substr don't work with cyrilic (I don't know but maybe) you need to know a string is an spécific array. So you can delete the first letter with unset.
`unset($string[0]);`
But use substr in priority :)

Comment: It does not work in cyrilic text.

Comment: [mb_substr()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) [Demo](https://3v4l.org/6jcaR)

Comment: @Xenofexs - nope, that will delete the first byte.... a string is a byte array, not a character array

Comment: Oh, okay thanks for the precision and sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$string = 'Добре дошли!';
var_dump(mb_substr($string, 1));
```

result:

```
string(20) "обре дошли!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Set encoding and then use mb_subtr

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$string = 'Добре дошли!';
echo mb_substr($string,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php)

```
$substr = mb_substr($string, 1);
```

> Performs a multi-byte safe substr() operation based on number of characters. Position is counted from the beginning of str. First character's position is 0. Second character position is 1, and so on.